# How can I set a password for shares in Windows 7 that is different than my account password?

Tags: windows-7, lan

How can I set a password for shares in Windows 7 that is different than my account password? If I'm on a LAN and want to share something with someone, I might not want to give my account password out for security and privacy reasons. I'd just want to share a `shares` directory.

Update:
i do the following but i cant establish access:
IN my computer i create an account named Shares with the password 123.
Then i create a Share with this command:

```
net share chirin=pathtomyshare /Grant:Shares,read
```

Int the other computer of my LAn i try to access this share resource using this command:

```
net use \\iptothesharedpc\chirin /user:Shares 123
```

the ouput is that everything works fine, but when i try to access the share  i cant stablish the connection. What im missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows NT does not support share-level security, so you cannot do this.

What you can do is create a new passworded account for network users, then add it to your share's access list. (You can disallow local logins and hide the account from "Welcome" screen by running `net localgroup Users friends /delete`.)

Comment: Hi gravity, can you check my update to give me an adivice of what im missing

Comment: @voodoomsr: What you're missing is the _exact_ error message you are receiving. Saying "i cant stablish the connection" is not enough.

Comment: the exact message depends on what i'm running. In explorer is "access denied", in powershell is that "the path doesn't exist".

Comment: i found the problem. The SharedFolder ACL does'nt have any rule to this new Shares user, so perhaps i created correctly the share telling that Shares user has read access, in the ntfs permissions doesn't even appears. ICACLS SharesPath /grant "Shares:(OI)(CI)R", and the access is perfectly safe now, :). Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itpronetworking/thread/f2988697-d4b4-4427-993c-333f3ea2e6e4

Comment: hi @VickVega i don't see how is related, can you explain please

Comment: Create a separate account and allow access to the share for this specific account only.